# How to load 2 lists based on 2 select boxes on change of first box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

From the title, you can understand that this one is a bit complicated, but it really shouldn't be.  I'm sure this is an easy fix, I just can't wrap my head around it.

I have select box A which populates select box B whose combined criteria populate list A and list B.  When select box A changes, the appropriate info loads into select box B and the lists ***should*** also get populated.  Currently the lists only get populated when select box B ***changes***.

It's set up so that on page load the first box A/B combo's lists get loaded.  I need to set it up so that when box A changes (and box B automatically changes) the lists get loaded for box A/B criteria.

What I believe is happening is that when I attempt to attach any sort of handler to box B (or box A really) it looks to the previously loaded info in box B instead of the newly loaded info from when box A changed.  I need it to look at the new A/B combo.

I've tried all sorts of handlers, javascript, jQuery:  .onChange, .load, .live, .focus, but I don't think anything will work unless it picks up the new value in box B instead of the old value.  I tried all this in the document ready function in the javascript and also in the .jsp:

```
<span class="caption">Business Unit</span>
<select style="margin-bottom: 20px" onchange="loadRatingPlans()"
    name="cde_bus_unit" id="cde_bus_unit">
<c:forEach items="${divisions}" var="division">
    <option value="${division.cdeBusUnit}">${division.nmeBusUnit}
</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

<span class="caption">Rating Plan</span>
<select style="margin-bottom: 20px" onchange="loadAvailableLimitInfo(); 
    loadBURPLimitInfo()" 
    name="cde_rating_plan" id="cde_rating_plan">
<c:forEach items="${ratingPlans}" var="ratingPlan">
    <option value="${ratingPlan.cdeRatingPlan}">${ratingPlan.nmeRatingPlan}
    </option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

This successfully changes the LimitInfo (lists A and B) when box B is physically selected.  How do I make it do the same when just list A changes?  Please ask me if you have any questions!!  Thanks!

Here is the code for the javascript:

```
//populate the Rating Plans box based on the Business Unit
function loadRatingPlans() {
var busUnit = $('select[name="cde_bus_unit"]').val();

$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'loadRatingPlans.do',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        busUnit : busUnit
    },
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //get rid of old rating plans
        $('[name=cde_rating_plan]').empty();
        //load new rating plans
        if (data != null) {
            data.forEach(function(rp) {
                $('<option>').text(rp.nmeRatingPlan).val(rp.cdeRatingPlan)
                        .appendTo('[name=cde_rating_plan]');
            }); // end forEach
        }// end if

    } // end success
});// end ajax

}// end uploadRatingPlans

//load the available limits based on which are already assigned
function loadAvailableLimitInfo() {
var cdeBusUnit = $('#cde_bus_unit').val();
var cdeRatingPlan = $('#cde_rating_plan').val();

$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'loadAvailableLimitInfo.do',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        cdeBusUnit : cdeBusUnit,
        cdeRatingPlan : cdeRatingPlan
    },

    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        $('#limAvailable').empty();

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            $('#limAvailable').append('<li class="limit-list" id="' 
                    + data[i].cdeLimit + '">' + data[i].nmeLimit + '</li>');
            $('#limAvailable').append('\n');
        }

    } // end success
});// end ajax

}// end loadDivisionInfo

//load the assigned limits
function loadBURPLimitInfo() {
var cdeBusUnit = $('#cde_bus_unit').val();
var cdeRatingPlan = $('#cde_rating_plan').val();

$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'loadBURPLimitInfo.do',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        cdeBusUnit : cdeBusUnit,
        cdeRatingPlan : cdeRatingPlan
    },

    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        $('#limAssigned').empty();

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].indDefault = -1){
            $('#limAssigned').append('<li class="limit-list, 
                    assigned-li-default" id="' 
                    + data[i].cdeLimit + '">' + data[i].nmeLimit + '</li>');
            $('#limAssigned').append('\n');
            }
            else{
            $('#limAssigned').append('<li class="limit-list" id="' 
                    + data[i].cdeLimit + '">' + data[i].nmeLimit + '</li>');
            $('#limAssigned').append('\n'); 
            }
        }

    } // end success
});// end ajax
```

Comment: Can you please also post the javascript portion of your code, specifcially loadRatingPlans(), loadAvailableLimitInfo(), and loadBURPLimitInfo()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.  The answer is to create a method that will return the lists based on just the value of the first box.  I go to the db and grab the value of the list for the second box and then return the lists based on the first value in that second list.  I already had a method set up to do this for loading the lists based on the first set of values from the first and second boxes on the page load.